# ADB Shell get Live GPS Location (not last known location)

Tags: android, gps, command, location, adb

The adb command: adb shell dumpsys location

It retrieves me "the last known location" plus other information.
But the GPS location seems to be stuck, even I move somewhere still the gps doesn't change.

Is there an additional command to get the Just GPS or also the GPS? or make the GPS change? (flush cache memory, update, etc?).

Thanks

Comment: Maybe silly question - Is your GPS on (in use by some application - e.g. maps)?

Comment: Obviously not in this case - that's the point of the question. OP and myself want a way to get the GPS location without something else triggering the request.